# as keyword in angular 4?

Tags: angular, let

Currently am learning about Angular 4 introduced a new keyword : `as`.

**AS keyword** – A new addition to the template syntax is the `as keyword` is use to simplify to the `let` syntax.

I have just implement this below code.

```
<div *ngIf="users | async as usersModel">
    <h2>{{ usersModel.name }}</h2> <small>{{ usersModel.age }}</small>
</div>
```

I can't get much details from anywhere for this below questions.

### Questions:

- What is the difference between of `users` object and `userModel` object*.
- What is the main use of `as` keyword?
- what is the difference between `as` and `let` in template?

Comment: unrelated: angular4 is synonym of angular, so only adding the `angular` tag is sufficient

Comment: Related to @Faisal's unrelated: the `angularjs` tag is specifically for Angular 1.x - you should avoid using it for questions relating to later versions.

Comment: I agree with you guys. this is my first angular 4 question. that's why am little confused.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have prepared the best example of using **"as"** keyword.

If you did not use it, your code would be less readable and it look like that:

```
<div *ngIf="users | async as usersModel">
    <h2>{{ (users | async)?.name }}</h2> <small>{{ (users | async).age }}</small>
</div>
```

In this example users is *Observable* object. Thanks to as keyword, you can assign to *userModel* result of *async* pipe on Observable object. F.e.

if users is `users: Observable<User>;` then *usersModel* is a result of async pipe on users variable, so it's like `usersModel: User` object.

---

@EDIT for question about **as** and **let**

I can't tell you what is the difference between *as* and *let*, because these are two different things. **let** is a javascript variable type, that:

> let allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block

**as** is a Angular keyword, which can you assign result of method/pipe to other variable.

---

This is your first post so I remind: Angular is not programming language, but JavaScript framework. Most things in Angular is related with pure JS or TS.

Declaration of for loop in Angular is copy of declaration for loop by array from ECMAScript6, f.e.

**for loop (ECMAScript6)**

```
let iterable = [10, 20, 30];

for (let value of iterable) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

**for loop in component template**

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
```

Keyword **as** is a shortcut of assigment to variable result of method, f.e for some pipe

**some.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'somePipe'
})
export class SomePipe {
    transform(value: number): number {
        return number * 2;
    }
}
```

using `<div *ngIf="someValue | somePipe as otherValue">` is like:

```
let otherValue = SomePipe.transform(someValue);
```

You get it?

p.s: Last paragraph in my answer is only mental shortcut, of course. If you want know, how ngFor and ngIf directives works "inside", I recommend you to watch [Nir Kaufman - Demystified Angular Directives](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVyw2njDoZw) lecture.

Comment: oh good! Here I have another one question. what is the use of `?` symbol on your code? Is it any **null** checker?

Comment: Exactly, it mean "if not null" and it's called "elvis operator"

Comment: Fine! can you provide your answer as for my 3 questions?  I hope you can.

Comment: `let is a javascript variable type`. okay fine! In angular 2 we have using `let-variablename` in template. I am asking about  it.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer misses one very important point: `async` subscribe to your observable to get you the resolved values.

Imagine this scenerio:

**component:**

```
user:Observable<IUser> = httpClient.get(url);
```

**template:**

```
<div>
    <h2>{{ (users|async).name }}</h2> <small>{{ (users|async).age }}</small>
</div>
```

In above case since you are using `async` twice, `httpClient` is making get request **twice**.

So to answer your question:

**Q**. What is the main use of `as` keyword?

**A**. `as` keyword makes your code look good, but more importantly **it makes sure you use async only once** for a given observable as I explained above.

**Q**. What is the difference between `as` and `let` in the template?

**A**. `let` is a Javascript keyword. `as` keyword is only recognized by angular template compiler. Both do the same job of declaring and initializing a variable. In some places, like in `*ngFor` both are replaceable. But in case of `*ngIf`, it expects a boolean variable in expression and `let x = true` doesn't return a boolean, so you can only use `as`.

**Q**. What is the difference between of `users` object and `userModel` object

**A**. This is already answered. `users` object is an `Observable` and `userModel` object is the resolved value of `users` `Observable`.